# What could make the Docker json-file logging driver not suited for production use?

Tags: json, docker, elasticsearch, logging

I have noticed, going through the Elasticsearch documentation pages, the following remark about the [default logging driver of Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/#configure-the-default-logging-driver): **json-file**.

> 9. Consider centralizing your logs by using a different logging driver. Also note that the default json-file logging driver is not ideally suited for production use.

Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html

I didn't manage to fine a clear justification of this statement.

What could justify that the **json-file** driver is not suited for production use?

Comment: I'm wondering the same. There is not clear justification in Docker documentation.